# wifi and wired connections do not work in dual boot ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, wireless, iwlwifi, wired

I've been having this problem for a little while now, which sort of gradually built up with no indication that I know of as to why.

I first noticed that the wifi would randomly drop, and I'd have to disable and reenable wifi for it to work again. However, a few weeks ago, the wifi connection dropped completely, and not even rebooting it and cold booting it had any effect. The wifi works fine on my windows partition, however.

I tried many fixes found on similar issues on this site, including restarting network manager, adding SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi" in etc/pm/config.d/config, as well as a few others that I cannot remember. None seemed to work.

Many threads suggested connecting to a wired connection and using apt-get upgrade to update the drivers, but the wired connection didn't seem to work either.

What was very perplexing was that the wifi was able to work fine on my university's campus wifi, but not on my apartment's wifi. I also tried creating a hotspot from my phone, which wasn't able to connect either.

Somehow throughout all this, when I booted up ubuntu the next morning, the wired connection decided to work again. Having gone through so kuch headache, I decided to just roll with it, and have been using ethernet for the past couple of weeks. I used sudo apt-get upgrade to update all my drivers the best I can, but I am not proficient enough in ubuntu to be confident in trying some of the other fixes I've found.

That has been workin for the last couple of weeks, but now the ethernet has failed as well, with seemingly no warning.

I do not know which terminal outputs I need to provide, but I will gladly do so once I do. I do know that my driver is iwlwifi. Currently my phone is the only thing I have that can connect to the internet, so I'll have to figure out how to get the outputs onto my phone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The output of lspci is:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8155]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
--
0f:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

EDIT2: dmesg gives:

```
$ dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp
[   22.317287] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
[   22.350229] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
[   22.350241] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   22.350246] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
[   22.394817] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   22.622712] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[   22.624882] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   22.625135] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   22.781398] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   23.239836] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0 wlp15s0: renamed from wlan0
[   51.415801] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp15s0: link is not ready
[   54.074379] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   54.074676] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   54.140999] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   54.141576] iwlwifi 0000:0f:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   54.162991] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp15s0: link is not ready
[   54.211514] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp15s0: link is not ready
[   59.071394] wlp15s0: authenticate with ac:a3:1e:e6:cc:10
[   59.076039] wlp15s0: send auth to ac:a3:1e:e6:cc:10 (try 1/3)
[   59.077911] wlp15s0: authenticated
[   59.078106] wlp15s0: associate with ac:a3:1e:e6:cc:10 (try 1/3)
[   59.078885] wlp15s0: RX AssocResp from ac:a3:1e:e6:cc:10 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[   59.080034] wlp15s0: associated
[   59.080061] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp15s0: link becomes ready
[   59.083767] wlp15s0: Limiting TX power to 36 (36 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:a3:1e:e6:cc:10
```

I'm posting this from my school campus wifi, which is working. I'm not sure if that will make a difference in the output. I can post the output when connected to my apartment wifi later if it does.

Comment: May we please start with: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Let's check the log for clues: `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp`